# Custom navbar shape with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

With bootstrap navbars seem to always look the same, every menu item is a simple rectangle.

Is it possible to have parallelogram shapes for menu items though? How would that work?

Here is a image of what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVnLE.png

Answer (score 1):

use skew css property

```
.nav>li{
    transform: skew(-21deg);
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

If you do not want text to be tilted,

then reverse skew  tags inside li,
and change the active, hover css of  tags.